# devise overrule devise SessionController broke login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, devise, overriding

I have extended the devise controller for sessions. To add some extra functionality when a user logs in. Now upon login, IF no username or password are entered I get error :
SessionsController#create

Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

I searched last week for up to 2 hours how to fix this anyone can help me out on this one? Would be highly appreciated

**How to correctly add my custom functionality but still preserve the Devise create action?**

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create

    @user = User.where(:id => current_user.id).first
    @moderated = Asset.where(:attachable_id => current_user.id, :moderated => true).first

    if @user.sign_in_count.to_i == 1
      def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        "/welcome/basics"
      end
    else
      if @moderated.nil?
        unless @user.has_photo?
          def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
          "/home/no_photo"
          end
        end
      else
        def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
          "/home/moderated"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your additional functionality consists of redirecting the user to a different page at his first login i would suggest defining `after_sign_in_path_for` in the application controller as suggested by the [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-out).

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  private

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.sign_in_count == 1
      "/welcome/basics"
    else
      "/other/path"
    end
  end

end
```

Please note that this only works if User is the only resource that can sign into your application. Otherwise you would have to differentiate in this method as well via the resource parameter.

Comment: Cannot do that, I have more logic in, but removed to have a cleaner example. Updated the code with full function now.

Comment: In general defining a method inside another method does not work the way you expect. The inner method only exists in the context of the outer method. Its not defined for the whole controller.

Comment: And you can't call id of current_user because the user is not set at this point in time. That's why the error "Called id for nil" appears. So if you override the create method without the main functionality it had before, he can't login, so i think just after the user signed in the current_user is available.

Comment: had it refectored, removed the devise session overrule controller and all works fine just had to do some if statement magic, thx!